# Android-Should remain on same page on Back press key on device

Tags: android

If I login giving password and username and it directs to the next page after that if I click back press key on my device not back button back key on device it should remain in the same page and on double click of back key it should run out of the app.

Can anybody suggest me some codes? ASAP and If I run out of the app it should come to the page where I left.
I want the app to get pause or remain on the same page where I closed it.It should not ask for login again until I Logout the app.

Comment: Why do you want to deviate from the 'standard'? User want to go back when they press back, not be stuck in the same screen.

Comment: What does "if I click back press key on my device not back button back key on device" even mean?

Comment: @DanHulme ahha it means when I click on back key in device(mobile) not backbutton of my app.

Comment: @RvdK It should remain on the same page when user click once and should close the app if user clicks twice.

Comment: I want the app to get pause or remain on the same page where I closed it.It should not ask for login again until I Logout the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the `onKeyDown` method in your activity and look for the back button. Return true so that the event is consumed.

```
    long backPressedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if (currentTime- backPressedAt < 888)
            {
              backPressCount++;
            }
            else
            {
              backPressCount = 0;
            } 
            backPressedAt = currentTime;
            if(backPressCount == 2)
            {
               return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            }
            return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

Comment: use flag also for double click.

Comment: i think he doesn't want that, he just wants to block back button.

Comment: he told "it should remain in the same page and on double click of back key it should run out of the app"

Comment: Lol, I just read the question header and gave the answer, my BAD.

Comment: @Rinkalkumar hahaha tsp has got it right help me out Rinkal...!

Comment: @ManNiPandiT Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @ManNiPandiT Please accept the answer if you have got yours.

Comment: @Rinkalkumar yeah thanks for that but you are not noticing what I asked again . I want the app to get pause or remain on the same page where I closed it.It should not ask for login again until I Logout the app.Is there only shared preference no easy way?

Comment: Yes, you can use shared preference the easiest way or you can use SQLite.

Comment: @Rinkalkumar yes I am using SQLite how to do it.I have created registration page,login page and that all is working. But I want  this " I want the app to get pause or remain on the same page where I closed it.It should not ask for login again until I Logout the app" how to do it .Is there any other way other then Shared Preference ah?

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Comment: Maybe some explanation would be helpfull...

Comment: So would proper wording in the question, documented SDK code should not require a whole deal of explanation!

Comment: No problem, just remember to mark the answer that works for you as correct with the check mark.

Comment: I want the app to get pause or remain on the same page where I closed it.It should not ask for login again until I Logout the app.It should come to the page where I left or went back on my device..! got me?

Comment: @ManNiPandiT is this what you wanted?

Comment: @RinalKumar Not exactly but now I want this too to happen.Could you please help out.

Answer (score -1):

Override the onBackPressed method on the Button Click. This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

First add `noHistory=true` under login activity tag into your manifest

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:noHistory="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

After that add `onBackPressed()` like below into your next activity

```
private int count=0;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      if(count!=0)
        super.onBackPressed();
      count++;
    }
```

Comment: well it worked .but on double click it is going to login screen again i dont want that i want it to remain on the same page on single click or on doubleclick it should go out of the app.

Comment: @ManNiPandiT Did you add that noHistory into your manifest

Comment: ya thanks man its working i din do that.Can you help me out on this? i want my app to remain or get pause on same page where I left back. It should not ask for login Until I give logout.

Comment: @ManNiPandiT you need to maintain session to achieve this. Use sharedpreference to store your session. Depends on login session you need to redirect your activity